Deploy docker-compose based app to heroku
Is there any way to deploy docker-composed based app on Heroku? I can't find the exact way to do this.
It seems like we should use heroku.yml and define service there, but heroku.yml requires Dockerfile in local but I want to use image from Github registry so I don't have Dockerfile.
docker-compose.yml file I want to deploy looks like this.
version: '3.8'

services:
  zitadel:
    restart: 'always'
    networks:
      - 'zitadel'
    image: 'ghcr.io/zitadel/zitadel:latest'
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: 'service_healthy'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

  db:
    restart: 'always'
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    networks:
      - 'zitadel'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-d", "zitadel", "-U", "postgres"]
      interval: '10s'
      timeout: '30s'
      retries: 5
      start_period: '20s'

networks:
  zitadel:

I need a way to deploy this docker-compose.yml file.
